# notepad++ adds \r to shell scripts

Tags: shell-script, windows, editors

I noticed notepad++ adds characters when writing bash scripts. 
For example a simple wait script written in notepad++ it adds \r breaking the script. The standard windows notepad does not have this issue. Is there a way to check or to control for these extra characters.

I've already tried the different encoding options within notepad++ (utf8, utf8 without bom, ansi)

Here is the sample script that works when save in notepad or nano, but not notepad++ (v.5.9.8)

```
#!/bin/bash
#Written in Notepad
echo I will say something and wait 5 seconds
sleep 5
echo then say something again
```

Comment: You can save a file in Notepad++ using "unix" line-endings.  It is a menu-selection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a Windows program.

Comment: Voting to reopen because it triggers a problem that's relevant to UNIX/Linux systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a menu item under Edit>EOL Conversion>Unix Conversion 
and save

This answer was described under the third link provided by Thomas.

Comment: It's so simple.

Answer (score 6):

You can save a file in Notepad++ using "unix" line-endings. It is a menu-selection.  See for example

- [How to avoid DOS line endings in Windows tools](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/How_to_avoid_DOS_line_endings_in_Windows_tools)
- [Change EOL on multiple files in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341660/change-eol-on-multiple-files-in-one-go)
- [Can I convert file format in Notepad++ ?](http://techtips-it.blogspot.com/2011/04/can-i-convert-file-format-in-notepad.html)