# not able to use unzip command in ksh script

Tags: ksh

I am not able to use the below command

```
unzip file_name.zip
```

for script in `#!/bin/ksh` this language.

I am assuming this to be incorrect because the unzip command does not turns bold and blue in notepad++. Can anyone help me with this ??

Comment: What Linux distribution is that? Did you install the unzip package?

Comment: Have you actually tried the command at a shell prompt?

Comment: Using Notepad++ so please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/242334/100397

Comment: What is happening when you run your script? Do you get an error? If so, what exactly does the error say? If it's a "command not found" error, do you have `unzip` installed on the system? If so, what is the `$PATH` inside the script and does it contain the directory where `unzip` is located?

Comment: So you are thinking it's not going to work, just because the syntax highlighting doesn't recognize it as a command?

Comment: Never "assume". Test instead. Give examples of commands that do go bold and blue. Notepad++ can add CR to lines, which can (for example) disguise your shebang shell name so the language type can't be determined (or even run the shell when you try).